# What is the optimal structure of a BLE app in ionic with cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am developing an BLE App in Ionic 4 with Cordova.
i was implementing the logic from this GitHub Repository: https://github.com/don/ionic-ble-examples/blob/master/scan/src/pages/home/home.ts

but i want to create an Bluetooth-Service and call the scan function in ngOnInit. i assign the array of found devices in the viewDidLoad-Method.

But i am not sure if this is a clean implementation of BLE. Especially i did not know when to call the different states (scan, assign found Devices to array).

When i run my app on an ios Device i find Bluetooth Devices and they are listet in the array.

My repository could be found here:
https://github.com/goodcare/tobimat

thanks for your help!

Comment: I realise that many questions on SO get shot down because their answers could be too "opinionated", but I think this is a brilliant one.. Too many of the Cordova plugin usage examples out there simply *don't* follow good practices and unwittingly lead less experienced devs down a dangerous road. So as someone else who is currently investigating better ways to implement BLE connectivity in an Ionic 4 app, I thank you for asking this one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

Make a BluetoothService as in

```
@Injectable()
export class BluetoothService {
    constructor(private _ble: BLE) {

    }

    //make all the api level calls here and maybe more if you want to cache it and use the infos from here later on in the app.

    scan() {
       return this._ble.scan();
    }

}
```

Next, Make a device model

```
export class DeviceNameModel {
    constructor(private _ble: BLE) {}

    deviceSpecificFunction() {}

    turnOnLamp() {
       this._ble.write(some arraybuffer);
    }

}
```

And finally in your page/s:

*scan page to scan and connect to a device.*

```
  export class ScanPage() {
     private _myDevice: DeviceNameModel;
            scannedDevices: DeviceNameModel

            constructor(private _ble: BLE){}

            ngOnInit() {
              this._ble.scan(scanTime)
                .filter(filter predicate to remove devices that you don't ever 
                        need to connect to)
                .subscribe((response: DeviceNameModel[]) => {
                   this.scannedDevices = response;
                });
            }

            connectTo(device: DeviceNameModel) {
               this._ble.connect(device).subscribe(() => do sth);
            }
    }
```

*Home Page to interact with the connected device.*

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    private _myDevice: DeviceNameModel;

    constructor(private _ble: BLE){
      this._myDevice = new DeviceNameModel(_ble);
    }

    onToggle(event: boolean) {
        return event ? this._myDevice.turnOnLamp() : this._myDevice.turnOffLamp();
    }
}
```

Please note that most of this is pseudo-helper code and you'll need to tailor your services, models and pages to your need.

Comment: Just for reference, I discovered a brilliant article just now that covers [Angular Observable Data Services](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services), which I used as a reference for the `BleService` that I just created in my own app. Combining the concept described in *this* answer with the Observable-based implementation of *that* article is a solid win,